# bwu_datagrid, how to override row background colors and add a row :hover color

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, bwu-datagrid

I'm trying to override the odd/even colors and give the row a ":hover" background color, but I cannot override:

```
undefined .bwu-datagrid-row.odd, 
.bwu-datagrid-row.odd:not([style-scope]):not(.style-scope) {
    background: #fafafa;
}
```

Here is what I've tried on my Theme html with no results :

```
:host::content .bwu-datagrid-row.odd,
.bwu-datagrid-row.odd {
      /* !important works, but it prevents me from doing a :hover */
      background-color: lightskyblue;
      background: lightskyblue;
}
```

Adding ":hover" to this last rule doesn't get trigger when the row is moused over. I'm hoping that this is possible, so when someone hovers on any cell in a row, the entire row changes background color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in `package:bwu_datagrid/datagrid/bwu_datagrid_default_them.*` is the default theme style module. It is supposed to be used as a template for your own theme.

Create a style module with the same name (`<dom-module id='bwu-datagrid-default-theme'>`, copy what you want/need from the shipped default theme to your custom theme.
Then only import your custom theme instead of the one from `package:bwu_datagrid/datagrid/` and only the styles from your style module will be applied.
This way you don't have to "fight" the default theme.

Comment: Yup, Thank you soooo much! :)
I was under the wrong impression that I needed the base theme to extend from. But, yes, the seconds I switched off that dependency, it all worked.

Comment: Spent a long time ro figure out how to implement this in Polymer 1 and run into lots of limitations, this left no time for writing docs ;-) I like the result a lot though.